# React to every app activation in Windows Store app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a Windows Store app with Live Tile updates using Background Task. When I activate the app by any means (click on the live tile, switch back to the app, etc..) I want to clear the live tile (I have a number there that I want to change to zero).

To be more concerete, I run the app, I switch to another app or desktop, then I switch ti the star screen and I see a number on the Live Tile. I click the Live Tile, I am taken to the app and I want the Live Tile to clear. The same functionality as the Email app.

I tried the OnActivated method in App.xaml.cs but it does not seem to get called at any time (I put a throw new NotImplementeExeption there and the app never crashes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put it in the OnLaunched method, you just need to determine where.

```
 protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        var rootFrame = new Frame();
        // Do not repeat app initialization when already running, just ensure that
        // the window is active
        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
        {
           //....
        }

        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.ClosedByUser)
        {
            /....
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Arguments))
        {
                //....

        }
        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            //....
        }
        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.NotRunning)
        {
            //.....
        }
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
        BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Clear();

        SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnCommandsRequested;
        // Create a Frame to act navigation context and navigate to the first page

        if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
        }

        // Place the frame in the current Window and ensure that it is active
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

If you look at the code, there are several reasons of why your App is closed/suspended. So, determine in which cases you want to run de code for updating the number in the Live Tile, put it inside that if, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the better place for such actions is the `OnLaunched` method. It called every time you appication start.

**update:** Hmm, seems you should react on both `OnActivated` and `OnLaunched` methods:

> **OnLaunched** - Invoked when the application is launched. Override this
>   method to perform application initialization and to display initial
>   content in the associated Window.

On the application start `OnLaunched` will be called. But when you switch to another app and then go back `OnActivated` should be called:

> **OnActivated** - Invoked when the application is activated by some means other than normal launching.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried that to with no effect. It looks like whern the app is running, I switch to the start screen and click the app tile that noting is called. It may be beacuse if the Visual Studio. Could you recommend what to put there to test it? Debug.WriteLine cannot be read when not debugging

Comment: I always recomend to put the brakepoints and debug to see, if they are working

Comment: it is not, I have a breakpoint in OnLaunched and OnActivated and when I switch from the app to another app, then back, the app does not stop at the breakpoints